# data integrity in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, model

On my project, the data sent by the server has changed. Small change, some foo attribute becoming foobar, but this has created havoc client-side, since I was unaware of it. It took me a very long time to figure out where errors came from.

Is there something (existing or planned) that can make backbone tell that it did not receive valid data ?

edit: More precisely, what I have in mind, is to feed BB with some kind of model definition object, detailing : field name, field length, required or optional. Something generic.

Comment: Do you mean the data has changed on the server, and now the data on your client is stale? Or do you mean that you want to be notified when `fetch` or `update` changes some field value?

Comment: The sent json is different, (different attributes names) I would like backbone to notice it and say that there is non-valid data.

Comment: I'm going to shill in a comment for my [backbone validation plugin](http://toddself.github.com/Backbone.Validator/). Caveat: I have not updated it to Backbone 0.99 yet.

Comment: @tkone is "Pre-Defined validators" generic in the way I described in the edit ?

Comment: Yes. My validation routine was written purposely to help protect a front end up from bad backend data, allowing you to provide a default value for an item which does not pass validation.

Comment: @tkone then I think this qualifies as good answer. Is your script the onlyone of this kind or is there alternatives ?

Comment: There are a bunch of them.  Google `backbone model validator`.  Obviously I'm partial to mine! Since I wrote it and I'm shilling it I don't want karma for it so it's just a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the [validate method](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-validate) on your model. Backbone by default has an empty implementation and you can check for attributes manually based on your app.

validate is automatically called by Backbone when you call set or create create new models.

How to use: (From the doc)

Return any value/object except undefined if there's an error, else return nothing (undefined).

If an error is detected, your model remains unchanged.

```
var Chapter = Backbone.Model.extend({
  validate: function(attrs, options) {
    if (attrs.end < attrs.start) {
      return "can't end before it starts";
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: nice, so I guess it is the place where it should be hooked, but I am looking for something generic, where all fields are described in a systematic manner.